# How to delete a published vscode extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I developed a vscode test extension and published it before, and now delete it.How to delete a published vscode extension?

Answer (score 11):

You can run [`vsce unpublish extension.id`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#unpublishing-extensions) to do this from the command line

You can also unpublished through the marketplace website by signing in and visiting: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/manage/ Right click on one of your the extensions to unpublished it:

[image: Unpublishing an extension using the marketplace website]

Comment: Thanks! The hint using Right-click helped me. I was looking for some 3 dots button or something to manage the item.